# Protractor 2.28 - headless Chrome 57 - linux - tests failed

Tags: linux, jenkins, protractor

I am trying to run protractor tests with jenkins, but I couldn't get it working. 
The tests are started but all fails with one of the following exceptions:

*from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
      (Session info: content shell=)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64)*

or

*Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"*

The mentioned git issue doesn't help me. 
All of them are running well local on a windows 10 machine.

The used versions local and on with jenkins are:

- protractor: 5.1.1
- chrome: 57.*
- chromedriver: 2.28

I have found some issues that chrome should be downgraded to version 55.* but the all didn't solve my problem.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It says window.angular is undefined. 
I assume it is not an angular site. 
Have you tried entering
Browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
Before you get the browser.

Comment: No I haven't tried it jet, but why does it work local and not with jenkins. 
So I supposed there is a version conflict or a problem with linux and chrome, otherwise local I would have the same problem, wouldn't I?

Comment: yeah, that's a little weird, but give it a try.  
That line should fix the "window.angular is undefined" issue.